# Selecting dynamic range in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

By activating a button in one excel sheet, I want to open the referenced excel sheet and select the range, as the number of rows, and possibly columns will be changing, I have been attempting to write a dynamic code to make this selection.  After trying a number of things, xlDown and xlToRight makes the most sense to me however I keep getting error, "Method Range of object worksheet failed". If I use the same code in the worksheet, it works perfectly, just not when I use it in another sheet.  Have tried referencing the workbook and worksheet as well.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\1.csv")
Sheets("1").Select
Application.Workbooks("1").Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
**Runtime Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_worksheet' failed** at above line
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

End Sub
```

Please see the code I have been using above.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `cells(1, 1).currentregion.select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CurrentRegion`

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim wb As WorkBook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\1.csv")
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Currentregion.Select
End Sub
```